# Getting SHOUTcast Meta Data Manually

Tags: android, streaming, metadata, inputstream, shoutcast

I would like to scan for SHOUTcast meta data myself. I realise there cool classes such as IcyStreamMeta etc but I would like to know why I cannot see the data myself.

I am using this URL (have tried others too):

```
http://www.shoutcastunlimited.com:8512/
```

My understanding is that I should see meta data within the audio stream data - especially when a radio station changes the current tune.

What I've tried to do is output sequences of printable ASCII character to see if I can see keywords such as "StreamTitle" but all I can see if anything is "LAME".

My code below is less than ideal but is there are reason why I am not seeing "StreamTitle" or other meaningful words?

```
  public void retreiveMetadata()
  {
    try
    {
      OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
      Request request = new Request.Builder().url( mStreamUrl ).build();

      Response response = client.newCall( request ).execute();
      mStream = response.body().byteStream();    

      // This returns 200 as expected
      ContextActivity.LogDebugf( "ICY RESPONSE: %d\n", response.code() );

      if( abBuffer == null )
        abBuffer = new byte[ nBufferSize ];

      for( ;; )
      {
        // Read data INTO the buffer
        int nRead    = mStream.read( abBuffer, 0, nBufferSize );

        //ContextActivity.LogDebugf( "ICY Data Read: %d\n", nRead );

        int nPrintableStart = -1;
        int nPrintableCount = 0;

        for( int i = 0; i < nRead; i ++ )
        {
          // Look for printable chars only
          if( ( abBuffer[ i ] >= ' ' ) && ( abBuffer[ i ] < '~' ) )
          {
            if( nPrintableStart < 0 )
            {
              nPrintableStart = i;
              nPrintableCount = 0;
            }

            nPrintableCount ++;
          }
          else
          {
            // End of printable range
            if( nPrintableCount >= 11 )
            {
              String sMeta  = new String( abBuffer, nPrintableStart, nPrintableCount, "UTF-8" );        
              ContextActivity.LogDebugf( "ICY[%s]\n", sMeta );
            }

            nPrintableStart = -1;
            nPrintableCount = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
      ContextActivity.LogDebugf( "ICY Exception[%s]\n", e.toString() );     
    }
  }
```

Here are some "LAME" examples:

```
02-24 16:58:01.570: I/System.out(26965): ICY[LAME3.98.4UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU|]
02-24 16:58:01.580: I/System.out(26965): ICY[LAME3.98.4UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU|\]
02-24 16:58:01.590: I/System.out(26965): ICY[LAME3.98.4IUb\]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any place where you are actually requesting metadata.  If you don't request it, the server won't send it.  Add this header to your request:

```
Icy-MetaData: 1
```

In the response, you'll get a header back (assuming the server supports metadata) that says:

```
Icy-MetaInt: 8192
```

Whatever that number is (`8192` in this case, which is a typical figure) is the number of bytes in between each metadata block.

The first byte in the metadata block indicates the size of the metadata block.  If it's `0x00`, then there is no metadata and it's back to audio data for the size of the interval.  If it says `0x02` or some other non-zero value, multiply that by `16`, and that's the number of bytes (`NUL` [`0x00`] padded) of text metadata, in a `key="value"` sort of format.  `StreamTitle` is the only one that's all that meaningful these days.  Some streams have been known to include other data, often for internal tracking.

Comment: Doh! That was very silly of me. My fault for cut and pasting different 'solutions'! Thanks a lot.